# Can any one please explain the steps to create baaners in smart target?

Tags: 2011, 2013, smarttarget, fredhopper, sdl-tridion

Can any one please explain the steps to create banners and triggers in smart target using tridion publications

Comment: Hello Habeeb and thanks for asking on Tridion Stack Exchange. Are you using SmartTarget as a user or setting this up for other users? The answer depends on whether you already have SmartTarget setup and if your role is user or developer. Some depend on your specific implementation, so additional background will help you get good answers. Have you followed the instructions in the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/) for your version of SDL Tridion and SmartTarget? The setup differs across versions.

Comment: yeah, i am using sdl smart target 2011, and i gone through the sdl document, but my question is to create banners that will rollover in site using smart target. how can we achieve this.

Comment: You'll need to publish your banners, set up your templates, and define your [promotions in the Business Manager](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2/task_08A4E97C9E214FCA8A154B12A027490C). If you're a business user, work with your development team. If you're a developer, then start by [updating your Template Building Blocks](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2/concept_6A75395FA6D54FB685E04F2F9ED9CC63).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you have done all the configuration set up for Smart Target Implementation.

***Trigger:***

- Define your Trigger first.

***Region:***

- implement SmartTarget page region by adding elements to your
  Dreamweaver Templates.
- When you have added SmartTarget page regions to your Dreamweaver
  Templates defining where promotional content is inserted, you need to
  add the ID values of the SmartTarget page regions to a custom field
  in the SmartTarget Manager so that marketers can map promotions to a
  SmartTarget page region where the promotion should be displayed.

***Promotions***

- http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2/concept_6A75395FA6D54FB685E04F2F9ED9CC63 describes how to add promotions to page regions using the Template
  Building Blocks provided with SmartTarget.

***Presentation***

- http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2/concept_6A75395FA6D54FB685E04F2F9ED9CC63#docid=concept_0AF5A0AB45814561978DF51D121E8730&filename=SystemManager_Presentation.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_0AF5A0AB45814561978DF51D121E8730
  describes the settings in the Presentation page that allow you to
  configure settings for lister, detail and compare pages to determine
  the attributes that are available to marketers in the SmartTarget
  Manager and Preview Page, and which attributes implementers can be
  access through the APIs.